# Unable to assign an admin back to a user in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

am facing a problem whereby after assigning a role to a user(whose value in the db is_admin value is 0) as an admin(whose value in the db is_admin value is 1) its unable to change back the role to a user from admin.i haven't understood the reason why coz Ive added the necessary database check in the update function..here is my update function in the adminscontroller

/**
* Update the specified resource in storage.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  \App\Models\User $user
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function update(Request $request,User $user )
{

```
    $role=Role::where('id',$request->rolename)->first();
      if($role->Role_name!=='Regular User' && $user->is_admin=1)
      {
         $user->roles()->sync($role);
      }
     elseif($role->Role_name!=='Regular User' && $user->is_admin=1){
         $user->roles()->sync($role);
         $user->update(['is_admin'=>0]);
     }
    //  dd($role);
    return redirect()->route('admins.index')->withsuccess (Ucwords($user->name). 'has been Updated Successfully');
    
}
```

i will provide any necessary details on request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you make a dd($role=Role::where('id',$request->rolename)->first())? I think this isn't well, you are comparing in where clause "id" with "rolename"...
your value is_admin in the db which type is, boolean?

Comment: yes its a boolean..this is what it returns

Comment: what about the dd()??? did you see the the if/else statements are equals???it's a typo error?

Comment: yes its a boolean..this is what it returns [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1veEOoPSbD2Gct2knxLLi6Ptr4IlZ-fTZ/view?usp=sharing) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: dd() returns a blank page

Comment: can you double check the if/elseif statement??? again, are equal the comparison you are doing

Comment: my bad it was a small error..thanks i had to doublecheck to understand it

Comment: good to heard that, if you can please close this post if all is solved